# Passing additional arguments to python pandas DataFrame apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df and I tried to iterate each row to map values of two columns to new values, but I have problems passing in the dictionary containing the map to df.apply

```
df.apply(lambda row: (map_dict[row['colA']], map_dict[row['colB']]), axis=1, args=(map_dict,), map_dict=map_dict)
```

I got the error message

```
File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

I tried to read the official doc , but I struggle to understand its explanation on args parameter http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

I have also tried passing in map_dict as either keyword or positional argument, but I still get the same error

Comment: @Micheal will you please provide full stacktrace ? Its hard to find problem from single line of error.

Comment: Does it work if you just do `df[['colA','colB']].apply(map_dict)`?

Comment: @Lafada this is the only error msg that I got

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `args` argument given to apply function is passed `func` argument (lambda function given). You are getting this error since two arguments are given but lambda function only accepts one argument.

Hope this example helps

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(100,110), 'b':range(200, 210)})

def modulo(x, n=5):
    return x%n

some_dict = {0: 'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e'}
print(df.apply(lambda row,n, map_dict: (map_dict[modulo(row['a'],n)], map_dict[modulo(row['b'],n)]), axis=1, args=(5, some_dict)))
```